# I want to utilize the final value to the main program

Tags: c#

```
class Class1
{
    public int userInput(int user_Input)
    {
        int final_Value;
        for ( int = 1; int < = user_Input; i++)
        {
            final_Value = int * user_Input;
        }
        return final_Value;
    }
}
```

i want to utilize the final_value to Main Program but it gives error on debugging..
and purpose for this is to take an input from user for example say 5 and this loop multiply this value like 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1
and gives us the output. which we can utilize in main program.
i am beginner in c#.

Comment: Care to tell us what the error is?

Comment: What is the exception being thrown?  You should wrap your loop in a try/catch to trap the error.

Comment: `int` is a key... you can't use it as a variable name.

Comment: You seem to be trying to program by copying something that you don't understand. Don't do that, learn what each part of the code means.

Comment: no acctually im not trying to copy.. i was jux thinking that how it could happen that i input a value and that valuse is multiplied  as i described.. and sorry on int <= user_Input there is i<=user_Input.. i hope now you understand

Comment: You just got 6 answers to your simple question, which happens to be so complicated since you did not provide a clear explanation of what you need, neither provide the desired output for the value 5...

Answer (score 4):

`int` is a keyword in C# and you cannot use that as a variable name. change it to something else.

```
for ( var i = 1; i < = user_Input; i++)
{
    final_Value = i * user_Input;
}
```

Comment: Also, `< =` is illegal. Should be `<=`. (no space)

Comment: yes you r write.. thix ix probably the typing mistake

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue with the code above is that you are using "int" where you should be using a variable. All you will have to do to get it to compile should be to convert the places you were trying to use an int to use a variable.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= user_Input; i++)
{
    final_Value = i * user_Input;
}
```

Changing to the above should compile, but now you will need to get the proper logic inside the loop. Since final_Value can only hold one integer value, every time you go through the loop, you are overwriting it instead of multiplying to the previous one.

Hopefully, that second part was enough of a hint that you will be able to figure out how to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've not told us what the error is, but the first one is that you'll have a compile error. You're for loop isn't constructed properly because you're missing the declaration of i, despite the fact you're trying to increment it. Try this instead:

```
int final_Value;
for ( int i = 1; i <= user_Input; i++)
{
    final_Value *= user_Input;
}
```

Comment: @ChrisF: Indeed... that'll teach me to copy and paste from a poorly written question!

Comment: yes thix was compilation error

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a variable for the iterator

```
class Class1
{
    public int userInput(int user_Input)
    {
        int final_Value = 1;

        for ( int i = 1; int <= user_Input; i++)

           final_Value *= i; // equal to : final_Value = final_Value * i;


          return final_Value;

    }
}
```

`final_Value` will initially be `1` then will be multiplied by `i` for each increment.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare a variable (`int i`, in this case) for your loop and initialize the `final_Value` variable:

```
public int userInput(int user_Input)
{
    int final_Value = 1;
    for (int i=1; i<=user_Input; i++)
    {
        final_Value *= i;
    }
    return final_Value;
}
```

Comment: @RehanManzoor: "you didnot got me" ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the other answers seem to be throwing away the value of `final_value` in the loop. Try:

```
public int userInput(int user_Input)
{
    int final_Value = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= user_Input; i++)
    {
        final_Value *= user_Input;
    }

    return final_value;
}
```

Comment: why we used that += sign in that

Comment: @RehanManzoor think about your code. Imagine you go from 5 to 1. Right at the end final_value would just be final_value * 1. You need to maintain the value of i * final_value for each loop.

Comment: other all code is rite..???

Comment: actually it gives use of unsigned variable final_Value

Comment: The other answers or the rest of your code? Either way it should be very simple to test. Use a small number, calculate the expected value and check your code gives you the same result.

Comment: See my answer, which assigns 1 to the final_Value var.

Comment: @DanielKelley: This function could be rewritten to `return 0;` ;)

Comment: @francis - doh. Such a simple question and I missed that. Long day - thanks!

Comment: @DanielKelley: The main problem is that we still have no idea of what calculation Rehan needs.